# Available UDP port

Tags: linux, networking, udp

I have a RedHat node behind central firewall and I would like to be able to check if the firewall guys have opened a port for me on which still nothing in listening. When I want to check that for TCP port I use telnet and I get:

When not opened:

```
[myname@78 ~]$ telnet myhost 4080
Trying myhostip...
telnet: connect to address myhostip: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
[myname@78 ~]$
```

When opened:

```
[myname@78 ~]$ telnet myhost 4080
Trying myhostip...
Connected to myhost (myhostip).
Escape character is '^]'.
```

So how do I do that for an UDP port?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using [Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) which you can install on RHEL with yum(1) using command `yum install nc`.

After you've installed Netcat, put it in listen mode on the receiving end ie. on the host you're trying to reach from outside world. You can do this with `nc -l -u <your external I -address> 4080`. This command will hang on your terminal and wait for any connections to port you specify on the command line.

Then connect from outside world, using Netcat again, but this time leave the `-l` out ie. use `netcat -u <your external IP address> 4080`. This command will also just sit there. Typing any input now should be visible on the receiving end Netcat. In case it is not, something blocks the traffic between two the two hosts.